# Joi: how to validate that 2 arrays are completely different

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have this Joi object schema

```js
// const Joi = require('joi');

const Joi = window.joi;

// console.log(Object.keys(Joi))

const ruleSchema = Joi.object({  
  conditions: Joi.array()
    .items(Joi.string().required())
    .unique()
    .default([]),
  restrictions: Joi.array()
    .items(Joi.string().required())
    .unique()
    .default([]),
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/joi@17.10.0/dist/joi-browser.min.js"></script>
```

I want to validate that **restrictions** and **conditions** don't have any common values.

I tried to use `Joi.string().disallow(Joi.ref('conditions'))` but it didn't work, neither `Joi.string().disallow(...Joi.ref('conditions'))` nor `Joi.string().disallow(Joi.ref('..conditions'))` did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [context](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#refkey-options) and [in](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#inref-options):

```js
// const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const Joi = window.joi;

const schema = Joi.object({
  conditions: Joi.array()
    .items(Joi.string().required())
    .unique()
    .default([]),
  restrictions: Joi.array()
    .items(Joi.string().invalid(Joi.in('$conditions')))
    .unique()
    .default([]),
});

const validObj = {
  conditions: ["a", "b", "c"],
  restrictions: ["d"],
};
const invalidObj = {
  conditions: ["a", "b", "c"],
  restrictions: ["a"],
};

console.log(
  'valid ...',
  schema.validate(validObj, { context: validObj })
);
console.log(
  'invalid ...',
  schema.validate(invalidObj, { context: invalidObj })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/joi@17.10.0/dist/joi-browser.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, I would try something like this

```
    const Joi = require('joi');

    const ruleSchema = Joi.object({  
       conditions: Joi.array()
          .items(Joi.string().required())
          .unique()
          .default([]),
       restrictions: Joi.array()
          .items(Joi.string().required().valid(Joi.not(Joi.in('$conditions'))))
          .unique()
          .default([]),
     });
```

Joi.in creates an array reference

Joi.not negates it

Joi.valid checks the valid values